# Symfony 2.0 Where do i put my base.css file

Tags: php, symfony

Im new to symfony and unsure as to where my CSS / JS files in Symfony 2.0. Can anybody give me some guidance.

I've been reading up alot on aesthetics but I reckon i'll only ever use one CSS file for my site, therefore I dont see the need of aesthetics just yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put mine in my primary site bundle and then published the assets to the web folder.

```
src/You/YourBundle/Resources/public/css
```

and then

```
app/console assets:install
```

which copies them to the web folder.

Comment: Note that running the `assets:install` command with the `--symlink` command will install them using, well, a symlink, which means that when assets change in your bundle, you won't have to publish them again.